# Unity: Rotate gizmo with an offset of 45

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, matrix, quaternions

I am drawing two wireframe spheres that I would like to follow the player around. When the player moves the two gizmos follow, however, when I rotate only one of the gizmos rotates.

The broken gizmo code looks like this, it should have an offset of 45:

```
void OnDrawGizmosSelected() {
  Gizmos.color = new Color(1, 0, 0);

  Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y + 45, transform.rotation.z), Vector3.one);
  Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(Vector3.zero, 5f);
}
```

For reference here is the whole block with both gizmos:

```
void OnDrawGizmosSelected() {
  Gizmos.color = new Color(1, 0, 0);
  // This one works
  Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(transform.position, transform.rotation, Vector3.one);
  Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(Vector3.zero, 5f);

  // This one does not work
  Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y + 45, transform.rotation.z), Vector3.one);
  Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(Vector3.zero, 5f);
}
```

### Default with no rotation (How I want it to stay when rotating)

[image: Default Rotation]

### Rotation around the Y Axis

[image: Rotation on Y Axis]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Quaternion` has 4 components, x,y,z and w.

Just putting x,y and z into `Quaternion.Euler` will not give you the expected results.

Instead, use `transform.rotation.eulerAngles`

```
void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Gizmos.color = new Color(1, 0, 0);
    // This one works
    Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(transform.position, transform.rotation, Vector3.one);
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(Vector3.zero, 5f);

    // This one works now :)
    Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y + 45, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z), Vector3.one);
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(Vector3.zero, 5f);
}
```

**EDIT:**

> Okay, that fixes the Y value, but X and Z are still broken. They move but not in the proper direction.

Then try

```
    // This works even better
    Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(transform.position, transform.rotation, Vector3.one) * Matrix4x4.Rotate(Quaternion.Euler(0, 45, 0));
```

Comment: `transform.eulerAngles` works too instead of `transform.rotation.eulerAngles`. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Okay, that fixes the `Y` value, but `X` and `Z` are still broken. They move but not in the proper direction.